# Null Pointer Exception Thrown in Inflated Layout

Tags: android-layout

I have the following code :

**1) Method For reading values from the inflated EditText and Storing it in ArrayList**

```
private List<String> getDynEditText(LinearLayout parentLayout, int resourceId) {
  List<String> contactDataList = new ArrayList<String>();
  int dataSize = (parentLayout.getChildCount() != 0 ) ? parentLayout.getChildCount() : 0;

  for (int i=0; i<dataSize;i++) {
     EditText editText = (EditText) parentLayout.getChildAt(i).findViewById(resourceId);

     String editString = editText.getText().toString();

     if (editString != null && !editString.trim.equals("")) {
       contactDataList.add(editString);
   }
}
```

**2) I'm Calling this method in some where else**

```
mcontactList.addAll(getDynEditText(mPhoneNumberLinearLayout,
                                     R.id.dy_phone_number_edit_text_id));
```

Issues :

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException

  at.dyn.edt.contacts.ContactActivityDemo.getDynEditText(....)
```

If I click this, it shows error at the line

```
  int dataSize = (parentLayout.getChildCount() != 0) ? parentLayout.getChildCount() : 0;
```

Please anyone help me out ?

Comment: provide full stacktrace please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple places NPE can occur:

- `parentLayout` is `null`.
- `parentLayout.getChildAt(i)` is `null`.
- `editText` is `null`
- `editText.getText()` is null.

You should always analyze full stacktrace to find root-cause of an exception.